# What does "+" means in HTTP Accept header?

Tags: http, media-type, http-accept-header

How could I understand this record:

```
Accept: application/vnd.my.api+json
```

I mean, is this "+" symbol is standartized (anyway, I have not find it in spec), or it is just a convention?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Accept header specifies a list of acceptable media types.
The "+xxx" part of the media type is called suffix. It is an augmentation to the media type definition and helps to specify the underlying structure of that media type.

[RFC 6838](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-4.2.8), "4.2.8. Structured Syntax Name Suffixes" defines:

> XML in MIME [RFC3023] defined the first such augmentation to the
> media type definition to additionally specify the underlying
> structure of that media type.  To quote:
>
> ```
>   This document also standardizes a convention (using the suffix
>   '+xml') for naming media types ... when those media types
>   represent XML MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions)
>   entities.
> ```
>
> That is, it specified a suffix (in that case, "+xml") to be
> appended    to the base subtype name.
>
> Since this was published, the de facto practice has arisen for
> using    this suffix convention for other well-known structuring
> syntaxes.  In    particular, media types have been registered with
> suffixes such as    "+der", "+fastinfoset", and "+json".  This
> specification formalizes    this practice and sets up a registry for
> structured type name    suffixes.
>
> The primary guideline for whether a structured type name suffix is
> registrable is that it be described by a readily available
> description, preferably within a document published by an established
> standards-related organization, and for which there's a reference
> that can be used in a Normative References section of an RFC.
>
> Media types that make use of a named structured syntax SHOULD use
> the    appropriate registered "+suffix" for that structured syntax
> when they    are registered.  By the same token, media types MUST NOT
> be given    names incorporating suffixes for structured syntaxes they
> do not    actually employ. "+suffix" constructs for as-yet
> unregistered    structured syntaxes SHOULD NOT be used, given the
> possibility of    conflicts with future suffix definitions.